# Generating a loop for Unique number with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to generate the unique customer number.  I did the following but I wonder, how can i make it in a loop, so the loop checks until it find zero generated customer number in the DE:

```
%%[

Var @NcustNO, @checkcustid, @ucustid
SET @NcustNO = RequestParameter("custNO")
SET @low = 1000000 
SET @high = 9000000 
SET @number =1010001

/* generate the customer number and check against DE but want to have it in loop condition */

IF EMPTY(@NcustNO) THEN

    SET @FcustNO = Random(@low,@high)
    SET @checkcustid = Lookup("DE","custnumber","custnumber",@FcustNO)

    IF NOT EMPTY (@checkcustid) THEN

        SET @uniquecustid = Add(@FcustNO,@number)
        SET @FcustNO = @uniquecustid

    ENDIF

ENDIF

]%%
```

Modified one after Kelly's suggestion :

```
/* for create */

%%[ 
Var @customernumber, @ucustid
SET @customernumber = RequestParameter("custNO")

IF EMPTY(@customernumber) THEN

    /*genrate unique 7 digit customer number and look it up against a DE for uniqueness :: a loop and a check - with SSJS*/

]%%

    <script runat="server" language="javascript">

    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var number = 1010001
    var low = 1000000
    var high = 9000000
    var filter 
    var layouts  

    //While Loop to check for customer

    while(layouts !=0) {

     var randnumber = Math.random() * (low - high) + low;
     var uniquecustid = randnumber + number ;
     filter = {Property:"Custid",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:uniquecustid};
     layouts = DataExtension.Init("DE").Rows.Retrieve(filter);

    }

    Variable.SetValue("@uniquecustid",Stringify(uniquecustid));

    </script>

%%[ 

SET @ucustid = @uniquecustid 

ENDIF
]%%
```

Status of above code : ERROR

```
Jint.JintException:  Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.
Line: 955 Char: 20
throw "There was an error retrieving the rows."
Source:  Jint
```

DE screen shot :
[image]

Comment: Any reason why you would not use GUID?

Comment: the requirement is to have 7 digit customer number...i wonder will it be done with GUID? How?

Comment: I did not know about the requirement.  Essentially, you are looking for a while loop, correct?

Comment: yes..any loop...that can happily take care of my need in the code..

Comment: Another question - is this being done on a landing page, or an email - or something else?  What is the context of this being used?

Comment: Its being used only for landing page..for example contact create form to create a contact record in DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on a landing page, you would probably be ok using Server Side Javascript in this case.

```
<script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var custnumber = DataExtension.Init("custnumber");
    //Insert While Loop to check for customer
</script>
```

I created a very contrived example of how this might work for your use case.  I created a data extension with just the primary key, and a landing page that would perform a lookup if there isn't a query string parameter of `custId` available. I tightened your range to guarantee it would require multiple iterations before finding a new ID available.

```
<h2>Results from Data Extension</h2>
<script runat=server language=javascript>
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var custId = "";

    if (Request.GetQueryStringParameter("custId")){
        custId = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("custId");
        Write("Customer ID requested: " + custId + "<br>");
    } else {
        Write("No Customer ID requested - creating new customer. <br>");
            var low = 1,
                number =1010001,
                high = 22,
                randnumber,
                newId;
        while(layouts.length != 0){

            randnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
            newId = randnumber + number;
            Write("Looking up Customer Id: " + newId + "<br>");

            layouts = DataExtension.Init("ssjs_test").Rows.Retrieve({Property:"custId",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:newId});
        }

        Write(newId);
    }

</script>
```

[Here is the working sample](http://pages.s6.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=1550dccf35ce5f74eaa21800101bc599579368cf38f97db2)

After the while loop, you would then need to create the new customer in the data extension.  This should get you moving in the right direction, and simplifies the code you have above.

[Here is some additional info on data extension SSJS functions.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/)

You can pass data between AMPscript and SSJS using [methods found here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/using_server_side_javascript_with_ampscript/).

Comment: so not easily be done with AMP? This generate unique customer number is part of the Other AMP script. I think can use SSJS with AMP too..I will try to see if i can pass AMP values to and fro with SSJS and make this work.thx

Comment: They do pass back and forth yes.  There is a `for` loop in AMPscript, but it's not the best method to get you where you want to be. You might be able to do it with AMPscript only, but it probably wouldn't be efficient. Updated the answer with additional link.

Comment: i didnot use SSJS before , do you mind checking above if it makes sense?? pls

Comment: This should work, but I've not been able to test it out personally.  I would say give it a try and see how it goes. If it's not working, we can address that.

Comment: Tried above but with error : "There was an error retrieving the rows."

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your DE setup - I'll recreate in my account and try to work through your use case today.

Comment: Offcourse...i added above ..thx

Comment: In this line `layouts = DataExtension.Init("DE").Rows.Retrieve(filter);` is "DE" the actual customer key of your data extension? If not, it should be.

Comment: Yes inplace of DE i used the Name/External Key(both are same) of the data extension in my code.

Comment: @Jack85 - did this help?

Comment: @Jack85 - I assume there is data available?  I'm certain this method works, but something else is causing your problem. Hard to figure out what it is specifically.

Comment: 1. I use your working example and run against some DE's and all worked except the actual DE.And i get the same error somehow. Your sample should work for me but just trying to figure out why gets strange outcome. 2. Also, i use your example for my code and still trying to figure-out why can't i get...i should ..

Comment: There is data available..i am certain too it should work..I will try to look more into ...if am missing sth.

Comment: Finally!! All went fine ... Special Thx to Kelly!!